# Reading a text file content into a list of integers

Tags: python

I have a file containing:

```
1 3 3
1 5 6
2 4 9
2 4 8
4 5 7
```

and I want to read it into a list of list where:

```
[[1,3,3],[1,5,6],[2,4,9],[2,4,8],[4,5,7]]
```

I tried:

```
def main():
    filename = open("mytext.txt","r",encoding = "utf-8")
    file = filename
    lst = []

    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split()
        lst.append(line)

    for val in range(len(lst)):
        val = int(lst[val])

    print(lst)

main()
```

but I'm getting an error saying

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: I think, what you want is already achieved in `lst` Try priniting `lst`
And the error you are facing is because when you tried to access elements of `lst`, its list only. Try and check please once.

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

```
import numpy as np
answer = np.genfromtxt('Test.txt', dtype=np.int64).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions and `readlines`

```
In [107]: with open('mytext.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file_pointer:
     ...:     lst = [[int(j) for j in i.split()] for i in file_pointer.readlines()]
```

List comprehensions are often much faster and more readable than other methods.

The above method is similar to

```
In [111]: with open('mytext.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file_pointer:
     ...:     lst = []
     ...:     for i in file_pointer.readlines():
     ...:         inner_lst = []
     ...:         for j in i.split():
     ...:             inner_lst.append(int(j))
     ...:
     ...:         lst.append(inner_lst)
     ...:

In [112]: lst
Out[112]: [[1, 3, 3], [1, 5, 6], [2, 4, 9], [2, 4, 8], [4, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: thanks but I'm more comfortable with the method that i used in the question. Could you convert the list comprehension to the "old-style" method similar to what I'm using?

Comment: @Maxxx you should be using the answers that are presented to you. saying "i'm more comfortable with..." kind of defeats the purpose of asking the question in the first place

Answer (score 1):

In your code, try replacing:

```
for val in range(len(lst)):
    val = int(lst[val])
```

with:

```
result = []

for row in lst:
    row_list = []
    for i in row.split():
        val = int(i.strip())
        row_list.append(var)
    result.append(row_list)
```

or more succintly:

```
result = [[int(i.strip()) for i in row.split()] for row in lst]
```